# Share CSS across multiple SPA apps (React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, express

Currently working on several micro SPA that are unaware of each other and they all live in an Express environment. I'm attempting to import a global CSS file that lives outside of the apps but it's not recognizing it.

Using `@import url(assets/global.css)` doesn't work and I think it's because the CSS file lives outside of the app "ecosystem".

I do not want to simply add a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/global.css"/>` to each `index.html` because I want the `global.css` to be bundled with each apps unique css in the built files.

Is there a way to create and import and global file that can be used across multiple apps? Would I need to make it it's own node module and reference it that way? It seems a bit convoluted doing it that way.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to import css from your index under very app? like import '../asssets/global.css'. if you are using webpack then it is absolutely doable

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to publish common components as a npm package and then add them as dependencies in your micro projects. That way you will not have to add references to global files.However,if you want private npm packages to avoid general public using them,  then hosting them may incur pricing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not secure nor possible to reference files outside the scope of the project. If you do `console.log(__dirname)` somewhere inside one of your microservices, you will see that the current path starts in your `src` folder and you cannot access anything outside of that (Unless you want to do an Ajax to your own server, and that would be really weird). Your html file however does have access to everything inside of your public folder, as webpack compiles everything and puts it there.

I would use a task automation tool such as [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to create a task that copies your assets folder into each of the microservices' public (or src) folder, then reference it to that location.